# Multiplying an integral with a continuous functions (of a random variable)

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, density-function

I was trying to follow along with a solution in a stats textbook, but something just isn't clicking about the solution with me.

I was wondering if someone could help me understand it.

**Context:**

Given a probability density function p(y) for a random variable y, it was shown that $$\int_{-c}^{c}p(y)dy = 1$$ for some constant c>0

Given that, we know $$\int_{y=-\infty}^{-c} p(y)dy+\int_{y=c}^{\infty} p(y)dy=0$$

Since p(y) is a PDF, we also know that $$p(y)\geq 0$$ and we let $$f(y)=y^2$$ which is continous.

The textbook then concludes that $$\int_{y=-\infty}^{-c} y^2 p(y)dy+\int_{y=c}^{\infty} y^2 p(y)dy=0$$

Intuitively, I can see it, but when I try to derive it, I can't figure out how. I think I am missing a key property or theorem from calculus.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Hint: with $p(y) \ge 0$, can an integral of just $p(y)$, over a range from any value to a larger value, ever be negative? If it's just $0$, what does that mean about the possible values of $p(y)$? Thus, with $\int_{y=-\inf}^{-c} p(y)dy+\int_{y=c}^{\inf} p(y)dy=0$, then what must $p(y)$ actually be?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting something. Any integral of $$p(y)$$ could be negative given an arbitrarily large constant and become negative. An evaluation of 0 would seem like it can only be a constant value. I'm not seeing how that factors in the $$y^2$$ being multiplied in.

Comment: If $p$ is a pdf. then the whole integral must be one. If the integral on $[-c,c]$ also equals one this means that $p$ is zero outside that interval. I have no idea what the $f$ is doing above.

Comment: @copper.hat it was a derivation of an expectation problem. Needed to show that $$E[y^2]$$ was bounded given $$P(|y| < c)=1$$

Comment: @halfquarter I believe your idea is of an indefinite integral, e.g., $\int g(x)dx = h(x) + C$. However, if you then have specific limits, say $d$ to $e$, you then get $\int_{d}^{e}g(x)dx = \left. (h(x) + C) \right\rvert_{d}^{e} = (h(e) + C) - (h(d) + C) = h(e) - h(d)$, i.e., $C$ has *no* effect. Also, I was getting at that the integral of a function is basically the area under a curve. If the function you're integrating is non-negative, the integral is non-negative and, in particular, if the integral is $0$, the function (if it's continuous) must also *always* be $0$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, that helped a lot thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is a pdf. you have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  p(x)dx = 1$.

If you are given that $\int_{-c}^c  p(x)dx = 1$ then you know that
$\int_{-\infty}^{-c}  p(x)dx + \int_c^\infty  p(x)dx = 1$. Since $p(x) \ge 0$ this
tells us that $p(x) = 0$ almost everywhere on $(-\infty, -c)$ and $(c,\infty)$.

Then
$E[y^2] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  y^2 p(y)dy =  \int_{-c}^c  y^2 p(y)dy$.

Since $y^2 \le c^2$ for $y \in [-c,c]$ we see that
$E[y^2] \le \int_{-c}^c c^2 p(y)dy = c^2$.